# Is there a name for page that contains system status and pending tasks overview?

Tags: homepage, dashboard, names, cms

We are working on the design of a CMS to manage webstores. We need to define a name for the home page or start screen of the webstore CMS.

Based on user research, we decided that this page will contain information about the system status and webstore pending tasks. The idea is to provide users with an overview of the current status of the system (e.g. product images missing, broken navigation links) and a summary of pending tasks that need to be done (e.g. unprocessed ratings and reviews).

**What is a proper name for this type of page?**

Since completed tasks will also be shown as completed, names such as "Pending tasks" or "To-do" are not pertinent.
We though a possibility could be to name it as "Dashboard", but after some tests we found out that users strongly associate it to a customizable panel that shows business performance.

Comment: "We need to define a name for the home page or start screen of the webstore CMS." <-- So why don't just call it "Home"? As far as I understand it is *the* home page of the story anyway, so why try to find a special name for it?

Comment: A home page is usually a website page. This is a CMS, a software. In the last tests, only 1 out of 6 participants clicked on the logo to find this screen again, which means is not generally understood as a "home".

Comment: Is it a SaaS or a desktop software? I'm actually not sure that logo clicks are very common for get to home anymore. I belive they are more used as a "panic button" when users got completely lost on the page (but don't have any research on this hypothesis).

Comment: For end users, it feels like is like a SaaS software.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is Dashboard, but if you don't like that on its own, add in a qualifying term - Status Dashboard, or something like that. Depending on how it's organized, the other term that comes to mind is Feed; Status Feed maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint Online (Office 365) this page is called **Service Overview** which is the first thing you see on the dashboard (link on the left navigation). If displays all services, their health and planned maintenance. It may be appropriate to your case.

[image]

Comment: The solution you show is very pertinent. What makes me doubt is the "Service" word, and also that in this case it is under "Dashboard". For my case "System overview" would fit better, but this is not a good label for the button to access it, is it?

Comment: @Carina well your system delivers services that your users rely on. Question is if you're after system overview, or service overview. Both names would fit as label on a button.

Comment: "but this is not a good label for the button to access it, is it?" <-- What about "Show system overview" as a label for this button?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you will be displaying list items to do or pending items and associated statuses. You can call it as "My bucketlist"